# Random generation code translated from R fails in C++

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am working on code implementing random generation algorithm for sampling from tails of normal distribution [proposed by Christian Robert](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4010). The problem is that while code in R worked properly, then after translating it to C++ if fails. I can't see any reason for that and I'd be grateful for explaining me what went wrong and why.

*Notice that the code below is far from elegant and efficient, it is simplified to make reproducible example.*

Here is the function in R:

```r
rtnormR <- function(mean = 0, sd = 1, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf) {
  lower <- (lower - mean) / sd 
  upper <- (upper - mean) / sd

  if (lower < upper && lower >= 0) {
    while (TRUE) {
      astar <- (lower + sqrt(lower^2 + 4)) / 2
      z <- rexp(1, astar) + lower
      u <- runif(1)
      if ((u <= exp(-(z - astar)^2 / 2)) && (z <= upper)) break
    }
  } else {
    z <- NaN
  }
  z*sd + mean
}
```

and here C++ version:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]

double rtnormCpp(double mean, double sd, double lower, double upper) {
  double z_lower = (lower - mean) / sd;
  double z_upper = (upper - mean) / sd;
  bool stop = false;
  double astar, z, u;

  if (z_lower < z_upper && z_lower >= 0) {
    while (!stop) {
      astar = (z_lower + std::sqrt(std::pow(z_lower, 2) + 4)) / 2;
      z = R::exp_rand() * astar + z_lower;
      u = R::unif_rand();
      if ((u <= std::exp(-std::pow(z-astar, 2) / 2)) && (z <= z_upper))
        stop = true;
    }
  } else {
    z = NAN;
  }
  return z*sd + mean;
}
```

Now compare the samples obtained using both functions (they are compared to `dtnorm` function from [msm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/msm/index.html) library):

```
xx = seq(-6, 6, by = 0.001)
hist(replicate(5000, rtnormR(mean = 0, sd = 1, lower = 3, upper = 5)), freq= FALSE, ylab = "", xlab = "", main = "rtnormR")
lines(xx, msm::dtnorm(xx, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower = 3, upper = 5), col = "red")
hist(replicate(5000, rtnormCpp(mean = 0, sd = 1, lower = 3, upper = 5)), freq= FALSE, ylab = "", xlab = "", main = "rtnormCpp")
lines(xx, msm::dtnorm(xx, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower = 3, upper = 5), col = "red")
```

[image]

As you can see, `rtnormCpp` returns biased samples. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: @BenBolker Right... I looked at code for `rexp.c` where `exp_rand()` is multiplied by scale... Feel free to post it as answer and I'll accept it. Otherwise I'll delete the question.

Comment: As an aside, if you sample single points you see no real speed differences. Your C++ variant may be better for vectors of these truncated Normals.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I know, this is a simplified example, not intended for real usage, made like this just to be reproducible.

Comment: Gotcha.  A vectorized version might be nice for the Rcpp Gallery. Interested in contributing a write-up?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I'll think about it and contact you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While one can use either `scale` or `rate` in `rexp()`, the default parameterization is `rate` - so `rexp(1,astar)` has a mean of `1/astar`, not `astar`.

If you change the relevant line of C++ code to

```
z = R::exp_rand() / astar + z_lower;
```

everything seems to work fine.